# Does "don't ask me again" for 'L' key on Facebook imply "Yes" for all future likes even if I cancel?

Tags: facebook

What happens if I check the "Don't ask me again" box and then click **Cancel** on the "Like this content?" dialog?

Does it do anything? Does it imply confirm in the future? Or does it imply cancel?

[image]

(I'm too scared to guess, since I only have one chance.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No; however, the checkbox is only effective if you Confirm, meaning it's not possible to disable the functionality entirely.